# Building a project configuration in Eclipse from commandline

Tags: c, eclipse, jenkins

We use Eclipse to build our projects.

In Jenkins we have a build script which runs over the projects and imports them to eclipse for it to build.

The issue I have is that all build configurations are built on every build from the commandline.
(Release, release_shared, release_static, Debug, debug_shared, debug_static)

This not only takes a huge amount of time but for many projects some of these configurations are not needed to be monitored yet.
What I am asking is there a commandline switch of specifying the project and then the specific build configuration to use.

using msbuild I would do the following

```
msbuild test.vcxproj /property:Configuration=Release
```

this would build the test project with the Release configuration.

In the documentation it suggests incremental build, clean, all but this is confusing as these all do a similar thing when actioned. There is also a switch for architecture type but nothing I can find that would point to project configuration as a whole.

Does this ability exist in eclipse ?

Comment: So you want to avoid importing the projects into eclipse on every build?

Comment: Maybe my understanding of a project in eclipse is not what it should be, however I was under the impression that a project has build configurations (like debug and release), currently if i import project x and ask for a build it builds all configurations (both debug and release) I wish to only build a single build configuration at a time otherwise jenkins says it has failed if one configuration has failed, this is too high a resolution for me to deal with (since most projects have 6 configurations, it's an embedded driver on various platforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After hours of searching and playing with Eclipse I seem to have come up with the solution offered up by this https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/advanced/headless-builds/

```
eclipse -nosplash 
    -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild 
    -import {[uri:/]/path/to/project} 
    -build {project/configuration} or all
    -cleanBuild {project/configuration} or all
```

I was looking for a command line switch but it's built into the build or cleanbuild switches.

Hope this helps others with the same issue.

Comment: The build-parameters project and configuration are regex-strings so be carefull if your configuration or project-name contains letters like '[' or ']' or other regex-sepcial characters

Comment: I have edited this very helpful answer to update the link, which was 404, but was 301 in the wayback machine.  The original link was http://gnuarmeclipse.livius.net/blog/headless-builds/